# PhpMyAdmin: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, vagrant, homestead

I'm using Vagrant Homestead. Connection to MySQL server works well via MySQL Workbench. But PhpMyAdmin doesn't work. It throws "502 Bad Gateway" everytime with a correct config. Same config for MySQL Workbench and PhpMyAdmin All other php projects work well.

After this:

```
sudo service php7.3-fpm status
```

I got this:

```
● php7.3-fpm.service - The PHP 7.3 FastCGI Process Manager

//some information

Feb 01 13:14:05 homestead phpMyAdmin[8030]: user denied: blahblah (mysql-denied) from 192.168.10.1
Feb 01 13:16:35 homestead phpMyAdmin[8032]: user denied: blahblah (mysql-denied) from 192.168.10.1
Feb 01 13:16:37 homestead phpMyAdmin[8330]: user denied: blahblah (mysql-denied) from 192.168.10.1
Feb 01 13:25:47 homestead phpMyAdmin[8332]: user denied: blahblah (mysql-denied) from 192.168.10.1
Feb 01 13:29:22 homestead phpMyAdmin[8032]: user denied: blahblah (mysql-denied) from 192.168.10.1
Feb 01 13:33:15 homestead phpMyAdmin[8644]: user denied: homestead (mysql-denied) from 192.168.10.1
Feb 01 13:33:16 homestead phpMyAdmin[8648]: user denied: homestead (mysql-denied) from 192.168.10.1
Feb 01 13:34:05 homestead phpMyAdmin[8644]: user denied: homestead (mysql-denied) from 192.168.10.1
Feb 01 13:34:53 homestead phpMyAdmin[8644]: user denied: homestead (mysql-denied) from 192.168.10.1
Feb 01 13:35:14 homestead phpMyAdmin[8670]: user denied: homestead (mysql-denied) from 192.168.10.1
```

How to solve this problem?

Everything works well in Windows, but now I'm using Mac OS. It's not because of nginx config. Because If I replace phpMyAdmin to simple hello world php-file, it will be ok.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct user/pass in the phpMyAdmin config. You can test it by logging into mysql directly with `mysql -u homestead -p`

Comment: The funny thing is that it throws 502 error with CORRECT user/password, but in the same time it shows the page with complaining for incorrect data (with status 200), if I put incorrect user/password. I tested mysql -u homestead -p, it's ok, but phpMyAdmin throws 502.

Comment: Is your user limited to a particular host (e.g. `localhost`)?

Comment: I tried to specify host: 192.168.10.10, 127.0.0.1, localhost - no affects. PhpMyAdmin throws 502! But MySQL Workbench client accepts 192.168.10.10.

Comment: We can see only `192.168.10.1` in error logs you've posted. And you are saying that Workbench is connecting to `192.168.10.10`. Are you sure that your workbench and phpmyadmin have same settings and are running from the same machine? Do you have your phpMyAdmin login page rendered properly?

Comment: Alex, it's not because of IP-adress. I'm 100% sure, that mysql workbench and phpmyadmin had same settings. But after I changed php version in Homestead.yaml from 7.3 to 7.2 everything works well. Magic!

Answer (score 1):

The solutions is here: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1045

It happens with new Vagrant Homestead and Mac OS Mojave as I see.

Just add php version in *Homestead.yaml*

```
sites:
    - map: example.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public
      php: "7.2"
```